# Different digital signatures produced by different signing technologies

Tags: openssl, rsa, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I have such an input:

- Digest (sha1).
- X509 Certificate, made by makecert tool. So public key algorithm is sha1WithRsa.
- Private key for certificate, also made by makecert tool.

I want to sign the digest with rsa signing algorithm.
I used following signing technologies:

- My own signer (actually using Microsoft Strong Crypto Provider)
- BouncyCastle
- Openssl

Each one generates and verifies signature fine. But I have 3 different signatures as output. 
I tried this many times. And these signatures are not random. I receive 3 constant different signatures.
How can it be? Did anyone have such a problem? Am I wrong in something?

**Update** 
Base64 values:

Hash: 
XN9ADbe4NVnSscjRGvBnWe1bDaw=

MySigner' signature: 
aRiRJgYmFKl8i8+FTUbr8Ah9sWybNw2XyFLVttaxrWzhj14nRuyL5qSXxaL4/B0etKZQH5qipZB04wx8+aoRnnHxNcLFddyxMk7aUmilo+58k4KyyK43qgyUOmPs6mWvmBHpDf0pcU6FrRiMB543pnYqBZGfmAlfG+Yjjdxbqw4=

BouncyCastle' signature: 
 
WP1iU2nuooneikMLCaWR9i03B+ISp8+P+C/OqYHNF0qGioIbaRWCPHhxJqhCJdayr6T/X2XPjE2XebITmSmnd4JQgyECK77ju7AxCgBxIAWvzwDFMrrFvQ05wt8KDiDbcnfrRKZK+cmf/SvyBwBdezGuCQ3mXu7joo5l9LxQrM4=

Openssl's signature: 
lRk/kX/+1vUmHLIKNmZy5h84K2ryu9GtfIp2XXeTsJJz96i7tqNg+EU/c9KkRhcbf4kFMt/O8HLLp9nNSrm5VafNCrPTmOWJMfRrRZxH1BR8sjqmITTSJOy6kNvkmHcrrwWehcfaBw8ItHp/2+m8NY5C/QL4W7hL8qt5KoN3q5E=

**Update**
Files with bytes
http://download.files.namba.kg/files/5637461

**Update** 
Code to sign the digest with BouncyCastle

```
        public void SignWithBouncyCastle()
    {
        byte[] digest = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\public\signatures\digest");
        byte[] signature = null;
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"e:\PresentCert\RootCATest2.pem"); // file with private key and public key
        PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
        object obj = pemReader.ReadObject();
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ackp;
        ackp = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)obj;
        RsaDigestSigner signer = new RsaDigestSigner(new Sha1Digest());

        signer.Init(true, ackp.Private);
        signer.BlockUpdate(digest, 0, digest.Length);
        signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

        signer.Init(false, ackp.Public);
        signer.BlockUpdate(digest, 0, digest.Length);
        bool r = signer.VerifySignature(signature);
        // r is true
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\public\signatures\bouncycastle", signature);
    }
```

Then I validate signature with openssl using the command:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey e:\PresentCert\pubRootCATest2.pem -pubin -in d:\public\signatures\bouncycastle -out verified
```

And compare files

```
comp verified d:\public\signatures\bouncycastle
```

They are different.

**Update** 
Corrected code

```
        public void SignMessageWithBouncyCastle()
    {
        //File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\msg", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("the_secret_message"));
        byte[] msg = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\msg");
        byte[] signature = null;
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"e:\PresentCert\RootCATest2.pem"); // file with private key and public key
        PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
        object obj = pemReader.ReadObject();
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair ackp;
        ackp = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)obj;
        RsaDigestSigner signer = new RsaDigestSigner(new Sha1Digest());

        signer.Init(true, ackp.Private);
        signer.BlockUpdate(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

        signer.Init(false, ackp.Public);
        signer.BlockUpdate(msg, 0, msg.Length);
        bool r = signer.VerifySignature(signature);
        // r is true
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"c:\bouncycastle", signature);
    }
```

And I used this openssl command this time:

```
openssl dgst -sha1 -verify c:\pubRootCATest2.pem -signature c:\bouncycastle c:\msg
```

And result was Verified OK!

Comment: Post the 3 signatures or analyze them and see where/how they differ.

Comment: David, I attached files with bytes. I analyzed signatures. They are totally different.

Comment: Is it repeatable? I mean if you run each signing technology one more time is the result the same as before? Maybe datetime is signed?

Comment: I always sign the digest attached above.

Answer (score 2):

You're using [RSA PSS](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2005). There is more than one valid signature.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But.. Can I somehow validate with openssl the signature made by BouncyCastle? I tried that and the result is INVALID.

Comment: What functions are you using exactly? Perhaps all but one of them is RSA PSS.

Comment: I examined RsaDigestSigner's code. Looks like it computes digest of inputed message. So in my case the hash is computed twice. I will correct it and test again.

Comment: David, I managed to sign the message with BouncyCastle and verify with OpenSSL. If they two are correct, then I have a mistake in my signer. Thanks!